# Spotify randomly lowering sound

Tags: spotify

So i am listening to **spotify** and **randomly** it lowers my sound. A while later, when i am not speaking or making sound (which might be it is picking up my mic and lowering) it goes back to normal. But when i make a sound again it lowers...

I have tried to **restart** spotify, **close** all applications, **force** shutdown spotify. Nothing seems to help.

Comment: How about a little information about the device you are listening to Spotify on. This may be more than just Spotify causing it.

Comment: I highly doubt it is only happening in spotify, so I will ommit this comment and write my answer for a system wide variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i reinstalled the drivers for my logitech headset and updated the logitech gaming software and rebooted. That seems to have done it.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has an option to lower the volume when audio is being recorded.

Normally this is used for converences, but other applications have been spotted to use this windows setting as well.

To change this, do the following, assuming you are on windows.

Go to the *Control Panel*, *Sound*

Head over to the *Communications* tab.

Here you find a setting that states:
*When windows detects communications activity:*

- Mute all other sounds
- Reduce the volume of other sounds by 80%
- Reduce the volume of other sounds by 50%
- Do nothing

By default it is set to reduce to 80%. Change this to *Do nothing* and it should solve your problem immediately.

Alternatively, it can be possible that you have set for mic sounds to be played back, and that you have something like Smart volume Normailzation or Smart Volume Management active which lowers the volume if a loud noise is played. If this were the case, it would happen everywhere and it would be more noticable. I just mention it here just in case.